# camera lens loosening

Tags: lens, camera-systems

At my job we use cameras for checking parts that we make.  A recurring problem I have is that the camera lenses keep loosening throughout the day due to small vibrations in the machine where they are mounted.

My question is this: Does anyone know of a way to secure the lenses to keep them from unthreading? Its been suggested a set screw but due to the location that would be difficult.  It cant be permanent eg. a bead of superglue, because there could be a time in the future where adjustments need to be made.

it is threaded. it works itself about a half a turn loose per shift. Not a huge deal, just kind of a side project I'm working on. The environment is clean; there is a servo that makes a "log" rotate. It seems smooth, but must be vibrating a little. Just enough to slowly cause the lens to back off.

The focus and aperature have notches that keep them from moving, Its the entire lens assembly that's the problem. Its an array of 3 cameras, only 2 have an issue of this happening.

Its mounted with 1/4 -20 bolts into 80-20 aluminium. the lenses have no pin/bayonette/mechanism.

Comment: What kind of mount do you have? Does it have a spring loaded fixating pin?

Comment: More information needed about camera/lens as all (at least I know of) DSLRs have a bayonet/locking mechanism to attach lens to camera.

Comment: its mounted with 1/4 -20 bolts into 80-20 aluminium.  the lenses have no pin/bayonette/mechanism.

Comment: I added the comments as part of the question. Uncheck my answer as the choosen answer so more people can take a look at your problem.

Comment: oops!  im new to this

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a low-strength thread locker. My first suggestion would be Vibra-Tite VC-3, which is designed to hold fasteners subject to repeated vibration, and is removable without heat. If you can't find it, I would suggest Loc-tite purple (or *maybe* blue, if you just can't get purple to hold). For any of the adhesives, I would start by applying a **small** amount in just one location on the lens's threads. Make sure to apply it close to the base of the threads, not at the start of the threads.

If you are very conservative with the adhesive, one application probably won't be enough. But the point is to dial in *just* the right amount needed, while still keeping the ability to remove the lens with a purposeful twist.

As you mentioned, I would not recommend cynaoacrylate adhesive (i.e., Superglue). Vapors released during cyanoacrylate curing into a confined space (such as inside the camera or lens body) can react negatively with plastics, emitting a white "smoky" residue, which could settle on an internal lens element and probably ruin the lens's visibility and clarity. Additionally, it wasn't designed to release, and it would require a chemical release agent.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the type of camera you are currently using, some points come to my mind.

- You might think of some kind of shock absorber. There are some foams that do that.
- Try to use a sports cam, like the GoPro, because the vibrations might be loosing something more than a lens inside the camera.

But in reality this is just a speculation, because we do not really know the conditions of the factory. It is wierd enough that a lens gets loosen, unless is just a thread lens of some kind.

Comment: it is threaded.  it works itself about a half a turn loose per shift.  Not a huge deal, just kind of a side project I'm working on. The environment is clean; there is a servo that makes a "log" rotate.  It seems smooth, but must be vibrating a little.  Just enough to slowly cause the lens to back off. The focus and aperature have notches that keep them from moving, Its the entire lens assembly that's the problem.  Its an array of 3 cameras, only 2 have an issue of this happening.